# Binary Search on a List in Java

Tags: java, list, binary-search

I want my function to return "YES" if the element is found in List and "NO
" if it is not found.

I have written the following code(binary search) but some test-cases are failing.

However, I wrote the code for Linear Search and all test-cases passed.

I have written this program

```
static String findNumber(List<Integer> arr, int k) {

    int l=0;
    int r= arr.size()-1;
    int flag=0;

    while(l<=r){
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        if(arr.get(m)==k){
            return "YES";
            //flag=1;
        }
        else if(arr.get(m)<k){
            l=m+1;
        }
        else
           r = m-1;                

    }
    // if(flag==1){
    //     return "YES";
    // }

    return "NO";
}
```

However the same code works with arrays and all test-cases gets passed.

Comment: Is this an assignment where you have to use binary search? If not, you could basically `return arr.contains(k) ? "YES" : "NO";`

Comment: @deHaar : Not as such, but i believe binary search would be fast so i thought of using it rather than linear search.

Comment: Yes, it would be faster (*O(n) > O(log(n))*) and implementing it from scratch is a good practice. I now want to find out what algorithm is used in `List.contains(...)`. Maybe it is binary search, but I don't think so...

Comment: Your implementation will be faster than `ArrayList.contains()`, but I don't know what implementation of `List` you are using. Depends on the implementation... You could accept the answer given by @ErfanAlimohammadi.

Answer (score 0):

Your binary search function is correct. Maybe something else makes it wrong. Ensure that your list is sorted and all numbers in input fit in int (long is not needed).

Comment: :I got the problem now.  Thank you. Array is not sorted.